# What's the best way to write "Ugly Dog brand Dog Food"?

Tags: grammar, hyphenation, trademarks

What's the best way to write this?   I'm thinking "Ugly Dog-brand Dog Food" as the most likely candidate... what is grammatically-correct?

Comment: Why are you capitalizing "Dog Food"? It's not a proper noun. (Unless "Ugly Dog" has a product line they call "Dog Food", but I still think it's less confusing to lowercase "dog food".)

Comment: You want to know how to write "Ugly Dog brand dog food"? Well, you've done it. I don't understand your question.

Comment: Definitely no hyphen. The hyphen makes it parse like "ugly, dog-brand, dog food"

Answer (score 2):

*Brand* is usually superfluous. If you write *Ugly Dog dog food* it is unlikely that anyone will misunderstand you. As David M notes, the intrusive *brand* is characteristic of spoken advertising messages; my guess is that it was originally inserted to distinguish brand names which might otherwise be taken as generic modifiers: “Ivory brand soap” as opposed to “ivory soap”.

If there is a real possibility of this kind of ambiguity, I suggest you look at the company's own literature. In the US, at least, the brand name will usually be followed by one of these symbols: ® or ™ or  ℠, indicating respectively that the name is a registered trade/service mark, an unregistered trademark or an unregistered service mark. You may  place this symbol after the name to mark it as a brand name.

Answer (score 1):

Further to the answer above, the word brand is redundant. I buy some "Persil" washing powder, or "Heinz" ketchup,  not "Persil" brand washing powder, or "Heinz" brand ketchup. So the answer would surely be just to say:

"Ugly Dog" dog food.

Comment: Redundant, yes. But advertising speak to be sure!  Think of old-time radio announcers. *… and remember to always give your dog "Ugly Dog" brand dog food, because, "Isn't every dog an Ugly Dog?!"*